# Navigation.pop causes global key collusion

Tags: dart, flutter

I have three screens(I am nubering them so you can easly understand) and all of them linked to each other by navigating first from page1 to page2 then from page2 to page3. Eventually, I am pooping them with Navigaiton.pop backwards. When ı pop from page2 to page1 I am Getting this error

```
I/flutter (11452): Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
I/flutter (11452): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2153 pos 12: 'attached': is not true.
I/flutter (11452): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart': Failed assertion: line 411 pos 14: 'overlayEntry != null': is not true.
I/flutter (11452): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4954 pos 12: '_children.contains(child)': is not true.
I/flutter (11452): Another exception was thrown: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
```

However, when ı proceed like page1 to page2 then pop page2 to page1. I am getting no error so it is somehow linked to page 3

Am ı doing something wrong with navigations? What does this error mean ı am not using any global key?

**EDİT!!: I figured something out. ı am getting this error while popping page3 to page2. I did not understand what is it but I do think it is somehow linked:**

```
I/flutter ( 6540): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6540): The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
I/flutter ( 6540): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3473 pos 12:
I/flutter ( 6540): '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter ( 6540): 
I/flutter ( 6540): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 6540): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 6540): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 6540):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 6540): 
I/flutter ( 6540): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6540): #2      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3473:12)
I/flutter ( 6540): #3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1146:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #4      WebViewState.dispose (package:aurorav10/Components/WebView.dart:45:5)
I/flutter ( 6540): #5      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3900:12)
I/flutter ( 6540): #6      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1709:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #7      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #9      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #10     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #11     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #12     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #13     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #15     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #16     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #18     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #19     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #21     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #22     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #24     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #25     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #26     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #27     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #28     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #29     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #30     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #31     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #32     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #33     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #34     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #36     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #37     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #38     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #39     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #40     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #41     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #42     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #43     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #44     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #45     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #46     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #47     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #48     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #49     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #50     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4848:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #51     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #52     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #53     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #54     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #55     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #56     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #57     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #58     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1707:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #59     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3755:14)
I/flutter ( 6540): #60     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1705:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #61     ListIterable.forEach (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:39:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #62     _InactiveElements._unmountAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1718:25)
I/flutter ( 6540): #63     BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2372:27)
I/flutter ( 6540): #64     BuildOwner.lockState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2204:15)
I/flutter ( 6540): #65     BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2371:7)
I/flutter ( 6540): #66     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:678:18)
I/flutter ( 6540): #67     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
I/flutter ( 6540): #68     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 6540): #69     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 6540): #70     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter ( 6540): #71     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13)
I/flutter ( 6540): #72     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)
I/flutter ( 6540): (elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
```

Codes:

PAGE1:

```
return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      return RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: refreshList,
        child: new GridView.builder(
          itemCount: dergiler.length,
          gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
              childAspectRatio: 0.7),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Dergielemet(dergiler[index], index),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    });
//this class is on other file but ı put this here to help you see it easly    
class Dergielemet extends StatelessWidget {
  Dergi dergi;
  int indexed;
  Dergielemet(this.dergi, this.indexed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 163.0,
      height: 247.0,
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return DergiDetail(dergi.image,dergi.name,indexed);
              }));
            },
            child: new Container(
              width: 163.0,
              height: 222.0,
              child: new Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    color: Theme.Colors.dergigray,
                    width: 163.0,
                    height: 222.0,
                  ),
                  new Hero(
                    key: Key(indexed.toString()+"asd"),
                    tag: indexed,
                    child: new Container(
                      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      width: 151.0,
                      height: 210.1,

                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          image: new DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(dergi.image),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,



                          ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                width: 163.0,
                height: 25.0,
                child: new Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.44,
                  child: new Container(
                    width: 163.0,
                    height: 25.0,
                    color: Theme.Colors.dergigray,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

PAGE2:

```
return new Stack(children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          child: new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              /*  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                  return Bottomtab();
                }));*/
              },
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 30.0,
              )
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0, left: 10.0),
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
//            new Container(
//              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0),
//              color: Colors.black,
//              width: 211,
//              height: 291,
            new Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black,width: 6.0)

              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: Hero(
                key: Key("sda"),
                tag: indexed,
                child: new Container(
                  width: 199.0,
                  height: 278.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new NetworkImage(dergiimage),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            new Container(height: 29.0),
            // İmage is over
            new Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: new Text(
              baslik,
              style: Theme.TextStyles.detailpagetitle,
            )),
            // Text is over
            new Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: details.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                      return DetailTile(
                          details[index].title, details[index].link);
                    }))
          ],
        ),
      ]);
//Other File
    class DetailTile extends StatelessWidget {
  String url, title;

  DetailTile(this.title, this.url,);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return WebViewPlugin(url);
          }));
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          width: 100.0,
          height: 41.0,
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0,right: 16.0),
                height:34,
                width: 34,
                child: new Center(

                  child: new Material(type: MaterialType.transparency, child:new Text("B",style: Theme.TextStyles.detailpagetilecapital,)),
                ),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              ),
              new Material(
                  type: MaterialType.transparency,
                  child: Text(
                "$title",
                style: Theme.TextStyles.detailpagetiletitle,
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Page3:

```
return new Container(

        color: Colors.red,
    );
```

Comment: It should say which `Widget`'s have the same `GlobalKey` in the exception message. Could you include that?

Comment: It doesn't show which widget's but ı edited something can you check it out